# Load data from internet in RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am getting movie data from the internet like its name, poster etc, but for the genres of the movie, I need to fetch it again from the net. So here's my solution for this problem.

```
public class MoviesViewAllAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesViewAllAdapter.MoviesViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<MovieBrief> mMovies;

public MoviesViewAllAdapter(Context context, List<MovieBrief> movies) {
    mContext = context;
    mMovies = movies;
}

@Override
public MoviesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new MoviesViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_movie_large,parent,false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MoviesViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.movieGenreTextView.setText("");
    setGenres(holder, mMovies.get(position).getId());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mMovies.size();
}

public class MoviesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView movieGenreTextView;

    public MoviesViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        movieGenreTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_genre_movie_card);
    }
}

private void setGenres(final MoviesViewHolder holder, Integer movieId) {
    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<Movie> call = apiService.getMovieDetails(movieId,mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.MOVIE_DB_API_KEY));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Movie>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Movie> call, Response<Movie> response) {
            if(response.code() != 200) return;
            List<Genre> genresList = response.body().getGenres();
            String genres = "";
            for (int i=0;i<genresList.size();i++) {
                if(i == genresList.size()-1) {
                    genres = genres.concat(genresList.get(i).getGenreName());
                }
                else {
                    genres = genres.concat(genresList.get(i).getGenreName()+", ");
                }
            }
            holder.movieGenreTextView.setText(genres);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Movie> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}

}
```

But here problem is that when performing fling and going up the recyclerview the genres which are showing is not related to the movie, the genres which are loading are random.
May be because I am loading data on onBindViewHolder and when holder disappears from screen it loads into random holder. Is it so ?

Comment: You should not make the call in there. You cannot control how many times that is called. Do it after retreiving the movie list, one by one, unless is posible to request several at once.

Comment: Also, you want to use `if (!response.isSuccessful()) return;` instead of the code.

Comment: @MatiasOlocco i did by checking its code by 200.
is response.isSuccessful() does the same thing ? didnt knew about this method.

Comment: It checks that the response is between 200 and 300 which makes it valid. I'm just suggesting it so you don't carry that condition all over your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are getting the entire movie list every time you create a view in your list. I am not sure how the server is returning that data but my guess is that every time you call the server there is no guarantee that the data is in the same order. You are getting a random order every time but trying to extract a fixed position of it and that is why the genres are not related.

The problematic line is `onBindViewHolder` which is called every time a view is created and this function is calling `setGenres` which is getting a new movie list which is in random order.

You can do two things to fix this issue:

1. Search for the movie first, find its index and then use that to get the genre. But this is still a very bad design since for a list of N movies, you are calling the server N times.
2. Get the list first, store it as an ArrayList in your Adapter. Now iterate through it without having to call the server each time

   ```
   public class MoviesViewAllAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesViewAllAdapter.MoviesViewHolder> {
   .
   .
   .
   List<Movie> list = new ArrayList<>;

   public void setList(List movies){
       //get data from server before creating the adapter. call this on your adapter and store the data here
       this.list = movies;
   }

   private void setGenres(final MoviesViewHolder holder, Integer movieId){
       //iterate the field list instead of calling the server
   }
   .
   .
   .
   }
   ```

Comment: then why don't you get the genre from the same list? If that list doesnt have the genres then add another field similar to that so that you don't have to get the genres everytime

Comment: okay so you are saying i should pass two lists into my Adapter. One of MovieBrief and other for Movie . That will work i'll guess..Will try that and mark this answer accepted. Thanks ! :)

Comment: exactly. and those lists have to be in the same order. ideally you would have one list that has all the data but that of course depends on your design constraints

Comment: yes it worked :) marked accepted...thanks pal..now i fully understood how to use adapters..i was doing blunders :P learned something..thanks again ;)

Comment: @HD aren't adapters fun? :) glad to hear that

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the wrong genres being displayed is caused by the recycling of the view/holder preformed by the RecyclerView . When you scroll instances of MoviesViewHolder and the view are reused so when you trigger the loading of a Movie details a ViewHolder is associated to a MovieRef but by the time the call to get the movie details ends the holder is now assigned to a different movie.

The best thing to do in my opinion is to load the Movie details and cache them in a map for example `HashMap<Integer, Movie> mMoviesDetails;` when the call to the API ends you can store the Movie object in there.

```
  public void onResponse(Call<Movie> call, Response<Movie> response) {
           if(response.code() != 200) return;
      mMoviesDetails.put(movieId, response.body());
      notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

Then in your adapter you can change the onBindViewHolder to something like the below :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MoviesViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.movieGenreTextView.setText("");
    Movie movie = mMoviesDetails.get(mMovies.get(position).getId());
    if(movie != null){
        /// set data to holder
    }else {
        //load data from network
       loadGenres(mMovies.get(position).getId());
    }


}
```

This is just sample code based on your current implementation, generally speaking I would not load this data inside an Adapter but delegate this type of tasks to a dedicated API class that can store the data in a database like Realm for example instead of using a map.